# Laravel's maatwebsite/excel import problem

Tags: php, excel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-excel

first of all thank you for giving the time to read this, hope you are doing fine.
I have a problem with a project I am making using laravel.
One of the functionalities of this project is that it can send an email to different mail @ that it has to get from an excel file.
so naturally I went with the `Maatwebsite` package being one of the most popular choices out there.
So the problem is that my imports file and also my controller can't recognize the package when I mention it in the `use` section.
I get the following errors:

In the import file: 'userImport.php':

- Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel'.intelephense(1009)
- Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow'.

In the Controller:

- Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel'.intelephense(1009)

I'm sorry if my explanation is a bit lacking, cuz this whole framework thing is new to me but I guess you will get it in the code below.

**UsersImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow 
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            "first_name" => $row[0],
            "last_name" => $row[1],
            "email" => $row[2],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**The controller file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Imports\UsersImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

class invitationController extends Controller
{

    public function import(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: How was the package installed?

Comment: I installed it using the command : composer require maatwebsite/excel. Then i published the config using: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by removing the package using the following command:
`composer remove maatwebsite/excel`
Then re-install it using:
`composer require psr/simple-cache:^1.0 maatwebsite/excel --ignore-platform-reqs`
instead of:
`composer install maatwebsite/excel`